# как сделать, чтобы R запрашивал значение переменных в консоли?

Tags: windows, r

Толькко начал изучать R и сразу столкнулся с проблемой. Пишу код в нотпаде, запускаю через командную строку, как описано здесь: http://datacornering.com/how-to-run-r-scripts-from-the-windows-command-line-cmd/

С выводом результатов на экран проблем не возникло, но, когда потребовалось считать значение переменной, получилось, что просто пропускается взаимодействие с пользователем.

Написал вот такой код:

```
{
name <- readline("введите свое имя ")
print(paste("Здравствуй, ", name, "!"))
}
```

При выводе получаю вот такой результат:

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.657]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2019. Все права защищены.

C:\Users\user>"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\Users\user\Documents\R\first_program.r"
введите свое имя
[1] "Здравствуй,   !"

C:\Users\user>

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить. Возможно, есть какой-то другой способ запуска скриптов через командную строку, который я не нашел.

Использовать Rstudio или просто R, к сожалению, не могу. Работаю с программой экранного доступа, там не озвучиваются результаты.

Answer (score 1):

программа `Rscript` работает в **не**интерактивном режиме. в таком режиме для чтения из стандартного ввода надо это указать явно. у функции `readline()` нет такой возможности, потому лучше воспользоваться, например, [функцией `readLines()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/readLines) (указав ей явно `'stdin'` как значение параметра `con`, и `1` — «читать только одну строку», как значение параметра `n`).

будет работать одинаково и в интерактивном, и в неинтерактивном режиме:

```
cat("введите свое имя ")
name <- readLines(con='stdin', n=1)
print(paste("здравствуй, ", name, "!"))
```

---

> Возможно, есть какой-то другой способ запуска скриптов через командную строку, который я не нашел.

так, к слову: например, у программы `r` (интерпретатора) есть возможность выполнять скрипты и интерактивно (с опцией `-i`) и неинтерактивно (без этой опции).

Comment: Запустил, как было указано. значение переменной ввести получилось, но в вывод ее значение так и не добавилось.

Comment: скопируйте три приведённые строки, вставьте в файл и передайте его программе `Rscript`. если введённая строка не будет подставлена в вывод функции `print()`, то я бы рекомендовал вам подумать о смене операционной системы на более приспособленную для программирования. например, на gnu/linux.

Comment: Видимо, неверно передал входные данные, когда написал имя на английском, все заработало, спасибо. Касаемо смены системы, скорее всего, так и придется сделать в ближайшее время.